# Functions rows query mysql returned undifined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I tried to create function that get the admin rows from users table mysql. Then I want to store it to the variable to check it latter, but when I console log it, it just return undifined. I knows this about async and should using callbacks or promises. But I'm really new about this, please help!

```
exports.admin = function(req, res) {

    var isAdmin = connection.query('SELECT admin FROM users where first_name = "yehezkiel"',function(error,rows,fields){
        if(error){
            console.log(error)
        } else{
            return rows[0].admin // returning 1
        }
    });

    console.log(isAdmin.values) //return undifined

};
```

Comment: Have you created the connection earlier in the code with `mysql.createConnection`? It would help to post more of your code, like when the function is used.

Comment: Sure, the query doing well and its still returning value inside function, but in the console log its return undifined

Comment: Can you please post more of your code?